# how to specify datanode port in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using hadoop2.4.0 for my testing purpose. I have to configure hadoop in my machine such that I will able to run hadoop in pseudo distributed mode , so that I can test independently on My machine. Also I want to make my machine as part of cluster.

But As I think issues will arise when datanodes and few other services which have there default port try to run on same port. So can any body guide me , how can I achive this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change following settings in `hdfs-site.xml` :

- dfs.datanode.address (for example: 0.0.0.0:50010)
- dfs.datanode.ipc.address
- dfs.datanode.http.address
- dfs.datanode.https.address

Comment: so these changes will be on datanode machines or on namenode machine, like if It is required on namenode machine , then how to configure this for different datanodes.