# Unable to import data using scoop: exitCode=255

Tags: sqoop

I am a noob in hadoop spark. I have setup a hadoop/spark cluster (1 namenode, 2 datanode). Now I am trying to import data from DB (mysql) using scoop in HDFS, but its failing always

```
16/07/27 16:50:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1469629483256_0004
16/07/27 16:50:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1469629483256_0004 running in uber mode : false
16/07/27 16:50:11 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/07/27 16:50:13 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: datanode1_hostname/172.31.58.123:59676. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/27 16:50:14 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: datanode1_hostname/172.31.58.123:59676. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/27 16:50:15 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: datanode1_hostname/172.31.58.123:59676. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/07/27 16:50:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1469629483256_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1469629483256_0004 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1469629483256_0004_000002 exited with  exitCode: 255
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://ip-172-31-55-182.ec2.internal:8088/cluster/app/application_1469629483256_0004Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1469629483256_0004_02_000001
Exit code: 255
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=255: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
16/07/27 16:50:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
16/07/27 16:50:18 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
16/07/27 16:50:18 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 16.2369 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
16/07/27 16:50:18 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
16/07/27 16:50:18 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
16/07/27 16:50:18 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

I am able to manually write in HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -put <local file path> <hdfs path>
```

But when i run scoop import command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<host>/<db_name> --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --table <TABLE_NAME> --enclosed-by '\"' --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \\ -m 1 --target-dir <hdfs location>
```

Can any one please tell me what I am doing wrong

Here is the list of things that I have already tried

1. Shutting down cluster, formatting HDFS, then restarting cluster (didn't help)
2. Made sure that HDFS is not in SAFE MODE

all the nodes have this in their `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.31.55.182 namenode_hostname
172.31.58.123 datanode1_hostname
172.31.58.122 datanode2_hostname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

**Configuration Files:**

**All Nodes: $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://ip-172-31-55-182.ec2.internal:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**All Nodes: $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/yarn-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>ip-172-31-55-182.ec2.internal</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

**All Nodes: $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/mapred-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>ip-172-31-55-182.ec2.internal:54311</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**NameNode Specific Configurations**

**$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///mnt/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50010</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50075</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50475</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/masters:**
`ip-172-31-55-182.ec2.internal`

**$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/slaves:**

```
ip-172-31-58-123.ec2.internal
ip-172-31-58-122.ec2.internal
```

**DataNode Specific Configurations**

**$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///mnt/hadoop_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50010</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50075</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50475</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: tried as `--fields-terminated-by ','` ? (single quotes)

Comment: error looks like - it tries to get connect to datanode1 but failing. what is `/etc/hosts` file look like?

Comment: thaks @BigDataLearner for ur reply. I have removed the `fields-terminated-by` just to be sure but the error persists. Also edited my post and now you can see the contents of `/etc/hosts`

Comment: also add hosts/masters/slaves files content of all nodes.

Comment: `datanode1_hostname/172.31.58.123:59676` - your cluster is running datanode(s) on 50010 port isn't it? Why your client is trying to connect at 59676 port? What port do you have set in hdfs-site.xml for datanodes(s)?

Comment: @BigDataLearner: I have mentioned all the configurations in the post. And I haven't mentioned any specific post in `hdfs-site.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am terminating this cluster and starting from scratch.

Comment: Ok ... this worked .. dont know what was the issue but I am glad that its on the starting phase of development

Answer (score 0):

From where u are trying to import the data. I mean from which machine you are trying to connect.check the master and slaves file in both namenode and datanode.

Try to ping the ip address from different server and check if it's showing as up.

Comment: Machine from which I am trying to import is not part of cluster.. Its under different AWS account in different location. I am assessing mysql by public IP. I can connect to mysql server through mysql cli client.

http://ec2-54-210-146-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:50070

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes and restart your cluster, and try again:

*Edit the part as mention in comment(#) below, and remove the comment*

`/etc/hosts` file on client node:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost yourcomputername  #get computername by "hostname -f" command and replace here
172.31.55.182 namenode_hostname ip-172-31-55-182.ec2.internal
172.31.58.123 datanode1_hostname ip-172-31-58-123.ec2.internal
172.31.58.122 datanode2_hostname ip-172-31-58-122.ec2.internal
```

`/etc/hosts` file on cluster nodes:

```
198.22.23.212 youcomputername #change to public ip of client node, change computername same as client node 
172.31.55.182 namenode_hostname ip-172-31-55-182.ec2.internal
172.31.58.123 datanode1_hostname ip-172-31-58-123.ec2.internal
172.31.58.122 datanode2_hostname ip-172-31-58-122.ec2.internal
```

Comment: Hi @BigDataLearner, Did what you suggested but didn't help.

Comment: Should i start from scratch again, I am in a kind of dead end here?

Comment: it seems 1nd datanode is using port `59676`, you need to add properties for in `hdfs-site.xml` file for both datanodes' `dfs.datanode.address`, and  `dfs.datanode.ipc.address`. both datanodes should user different ports for both properties, so you need to find out 4 open ports on cluster and use them - you can use this as reference - [hdfs-deafult.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml), these are default settings but you need to overwrite in [hdfs-site.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617474/how-to-specify-datanode-port-in-hadoop)

Comment: update the hdfs-site.xml as per ur suggestion but nothing happened. P.S. Thanks for replying